# Insert NULL with ADO from Delphi to SQL Server 2000

Tags: delphi, sql-server-2000, ado

I am trying to insert data into a SQL Server 2000 database with the help of ADO in Delphi 2007.

So far I've written something like this:

```
insert into (a,b)
select :a,:b

qry.parameters.parambyname('a').value := '';
qry.parameters.parambyname('b').value := '';
```

The error I get is:

> *Disallowed implicit conversion from data type text to data type nvarchar...
>
>   use the convert function to run this query.*

The columns in the table allow NULL values.

What I want is that the SQL Server table shows NULL where the value is ''. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What are your field and parameter types? And why are you setting the parameters to an empty string when you want to insert null? Empty strings and nulls aren't the same thing.

Comment: I am using a gridview which have empty fields and the value becomes ''. I use Clone.Fields.FieldByName('a').AsString;

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Variants.Null

Comment: Clone.Fields.FieldByName('a').AsVariant (or just Clone.Fields.FieldByName('a').Value, which means the same thing here) would be an improvement as it preserves null values, but as a word of warning, it would not convert empty strings to nulls, it would merely avoid converting nulls to empty strings.

Comment: I get a 'Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided.'

Comment: So again, what are your field and parameter types?

Comment: fields are asstring? I tried asvariant got the same error as when I set it to NULL.
parameters are set to value?
Sql columns are nvarchar(255)
It seems I can't send in Null values into the table, but if I am in the database I can insert Null into the table.

Comment: I mean the values of `field.DataType` and `parameter.DataType`.

Comment: the parameter contains ftString, the fields.fieldbyname('a') is inaccessible

Comment: your `insert` syntax is kinda odd...
have your tried: `insert into your_table_name(a, b) values(:a,:b)`?. 
and `qry.parameters.parambyname('a').value := Null` should work just fine.

Comment: Thank u everyone and especially @kobik , this one works. But I am wondering one more thing. I can't seem to get the information from the cells(if they are numbers) if they aren't formatted as text. What could this depend on?

Comment: @Joe, "But I am wondering one more thing..." this is really a new question, and can't be answered via comments.

Comment: @kobik, thanks a lot for the help! I will try to fix the other problem, otherwise I'll probably come back and ask a question one more time.

Answer (score 2):

you can replace with theses lines

```
qry.parameters.parambyname('a').value := Null;
qry.parameters.parambyname('b').value := Null;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
qry.parameters.parambyname('a').value := unassigned;
```

Comment: I tried this but i get the error
'Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided.'

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
qry.parameters.parambyname('a').value := Null;
qry.parameters.parambyname('b').value := Null;
```

or

do not set parameters at all - by default parameters are set to "Null".

Null is a special type of Variant (uses Variants), which defines an empty value (has no type).

Comment: I tried this but i get the error
'Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided.'

Answer (score 1):

```
qry.parameters.parambyname('a').AsVariant:= Null;
```

must be

```
<TAdoDataSet>.FieldByName('a').AsVariant:= Null;
```

Comment: Undeclared identifier AsVariant

Comment: Yes, it's rigth. I'm overlooking the property. It must be the 'FieldByName'

Answer (score 1):

Try

`qry.parameters.parambyname('a').Clear;`

Answer (score 1):

Do not write `null`; it is `nil`:

```
<TAdoDataSet>.FieldByName('a').AsVariant:= Nil;
```

Answer (score 1):

add in uses --> Variants;

after you can replace with theses lines

```
qry.parameters.parambyname('a').value := Null;
qry.parameters.parambyname('b').value := Null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an ADOQuery, Write a "Select" for your table. I use that a lot.

```
Select * From MyTable Where 0=1
```

And double click on the ADOquery component. A field list window will be appeared. Add all fields (right click). This way you can use your fields within your Delphi code.

```
MyTable.Open;
MyTable.Append;
MyTableAFieldFromMyTable.AsInteger := 0;
MyTableAStringFieldFromMyTable.AsString := 'Hello, World';
MyTable.Post;
```

When it comes to your question:

```
MyTableAnotherFieldFromMyTable.Clear;
```

will set the value to NULL as we know it in SQL server.
Edit: I just checked a working code. I clear the field Video from a table in following code.

```
Ornek.Open;
Ornek.Edit;
OrnekVideo.Clear;
```

Query is just "select * from Ornek Where 0=1" and I do the assignments in Delphi code using fields' .AsInteger, .AsString etc properties.

Comment: I just checked some working code of mine and a method named clear exists. Did you just add fields and use the field's methods? I mean not tables or parameters. Just write a select statement, write Delphi code to fill the field values instead of writing insert statements to the query component. ADO will do the rest and it will automatically create an insert query behind.

Comment: Maybe mine is different, If i check the class it says TCustomADODataSet. Sorry but I am a somewhat newb.

Comment: You should use TADOQuery instead. It is clever enough to create Delete and Insert queries from a Select query and this process is totally transparent to the programmer.